# Set List Item (li) exactly in center of page

Tags: html, css, web

Here is my simple code:

```
<ul>
  <li>
      Example1
  </li>
  <li>
      Example12
  </li>
  <li>
      Example13
  </li>
</ul>
```

with this `css`:

```
ul
{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3vh;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li
{
    display: inline;
}
```

And `"Example1"` dose not exactly in center of page.
this is how it look like now(`black` line mean center of page, replace `"Home"` with `"Example1"`):

[image]

How i can fix it to appear look like this(`black` line mean center of page):

[image]

Comment: Please  make your question proper.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Define your `li` `display:inline-block;` and your `ul` define `box-sizing:border-box` `left:0;right:0;`

```css
ul
{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3vh;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;right:0;
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style-type: none;box-sizing:border-box
}
li
{
    padding-left: 3vh;
    padding-right: 3vh;
    display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
margin:0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    Home
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i test. no difference!

Comment: @mlibre now define your ul box-sizing:border-box;

Comment: @mlibre now remove width  100% and add left right 0 in your ul check to my updated answer

Comment: @mlibre can u check to this  fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6vygcybt/ and tell me what is wrong in this fiddle

Comment: box-sizing:border-box fix this. Thnaks.
left and ... no neccesery